# How to determine if this problem is decidable?

Tags: computability, decision-problem, rice-theorem

I am currently stuck on the following problem:

**Given a WHILE-program P and the knowledge that all input variales are set to 0, is it decidable if a specific instruction is reached 1000 times?**

My intuition is that it is not decidable. Rice's theorem says that a non-trivial property of a program is always undicidable. But I am not sure if "a specific instruction is reached x times" even qualifies as a "property of a program".

I am stuck on this for a while now, so I hope someone can give a hint where to look to find an answer to this problem. Thank you so much! All help is greatly apprechiated.

Comment: Consider you have this program. Take any while-program and put any instruction 1000 times just before halt. Next run your program and ask if this instruction will be reached 1000 times. Bingo, halting is solved.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly, that I can reduce my problem to the halting problem and, by doing this, show, that my problem is not decidable? If so, how does the translating function look like? And how can I write down "an instruction is reached x times" in a formal manner? Anyway, thank you a lot for your contribution. :)

Comment: that is why I wrote down comment not an answer. Formal proof is possible but little tedious. Idea is that last while-loop have condition c. Put while-loop with 1000 instructions just before it is finishing under the same condition, etc...

Answer (score 3):

As [Konstantin Vladimirov](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/107037/konstantin-vladimirov) said in the [comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/111270/how-to-determine-if-this-problem-is-decidable#comment237655_111270): Consider you have this program. Take any while-program and put any instruction 1000 times just before halt. Next run your program and ask if this instruction will be reached 1000 times. Bingo, halting is solved.